# The download doesn't work as expected. I'm a beginner in php

Tags: php, download

I have a problem. I made a little download code. All i'm getting is a blank page.
Url to download: https://jonasgamertv.com/download.php?file=header.png
This is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["file"])){

    // Get parameters
    $images = array("header.png");
    $file = urldecode($_GET["file"]); // Decode URL-encoded string

    if(in_array($file, $images, true)){
        $filepath = "../images/" . $file;

        // Process download
        if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
            flush(); // Flush system output buffer
            readfile("$filepath");
            exit;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "File does not exist.";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help and time,
Jonas

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Assuming error reporting is enabled, this code would give you a blank page if `file_exists()` returns false.

Comment: Given that https://jonasgamertv.com/images/header.png is a valid image, it looks like the path is wrong - you don't need the `../` (assuming that's the image you're trying to download, of course)

Comment: He wouldn't see an error... The code is fine... bet it's the path file

Comment: Hi! Thank you all for your answers. I debugged it myself. The path is right but the $_REQUEST["file"] is empty. i checked that by adding an echo after line 2. IIs there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine; what I would do is check the path of your `../images` folder.

I added a new `else` clause to tell you if the file does not exist. This will let you know when the file is not found, since your current code just skips that altogether.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["file"])){
    echo 'Loading...';
    // Get parameters
    $images = array("header.png");
    $file = urldecode($_GET["file"]); // Decode URL-encoded string

    if(in_array($file, $images, true)){
        $filepath = "images/" . $file;
        // Process download
        if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            echo 'Preparing download...';
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
            flush(); // Flush system output buffer
            readfile("$filepath");
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'File does not exist.';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Not authorized.";
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to code around that issue - it is a one time setup issue. The task here is to find out what the actual issue is. You are _guessing_, that is not _answering_.

Comment: I am not guessing, I ran the script with no problem at all. I tried adding a header image in the right path and I downloaded the file successfully, so the `else` clause just lets them know the file was not found.